# React build not force browser to fetch latest version

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

Upgraded react-scripts from v1.1.5 to v2.0.5 as well as webpack from v3.12.0 to v4.19.1

Everything works except npm run build.

First it's not generating unique hash chunk file anymore.
No matter what changes I made and how many times I run the build it keeps generating the same hash file name.

I work around it by changing the webpack.config to following:

filename: 'static/js/[name].[hash].js',
chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].[hash].chunk.js',

It was previously like this below:

filename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js',

Now it finally generating unique hash chunk file however the browser did not fetch the latest update.
I do see the browser reload and detected a new version but after it still showing previous version until I Ctrl + F5 to do a hard refresh....This is gonna be a problem as I can't have the user Ctrl + F5 everytime we release a patch.

I'm not expert in webpack so I don't know what else information should be posted here.

Any helps is appreciated.

[image]

Update: I think the problem come from my service worker.
Although it is reload the browser but it is not fetching update ever since I upgraded webpack and react-scripts..

Below is my service worker code, hoping someone can shed some light to me.

```
// In production, we register a service worker to serve assets from local cache.

// This lets the app load faster on subsequent visits in production, and gives
// it offline capabilities. However, it also means that developers (and users)
// will only see deployed updates on the "N+1" visit to a page, since previously
// cached resources are updated in the background.

// This link also includes instructions on opting out of this behavior.

const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
    // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
    window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
    // 127.0.0.1/8 is considered localhost for IPv4.
    window.location.hostname.match(
      /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
    )
);

export default function register() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
      // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
      // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2374
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (!isLocalhost) {
        // Is not local host. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl);
      } else {
        // This is running on localhost. Lets check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl);
      }
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the old content will have been purged and
              // the fresh content will have been added to the cache.
              // It's the perfect time to display a "New content is
              // available; please refresh." message in your web app.

              //hard refresh
              window.location.reload(true);
              console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl) {
  // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
  fetch(swUrl)
    .then(response => {
      // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        response.headers.get('content-type').indexOf('javascript') === -1
      ) {
        // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
        registerValidSW(swUrl);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
      );
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```